# Is it possible to generate a chart with this very specific background?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I need to create a chart, that has a grid like in the following picture.
[image: Grid for chart]
The key factors being:

1. The x-axis is time with each tick marking 30 seconds
2. y-axes labels in the chart repeat at a variable interval
3. Chart must grow with the amount of data (i.e. for 30 minutes of data, it should be 60 boxes wide)

I have been looking into matplotlib for a bit, and it seems promising. I also managed to fill the chart with data. See my result for 40 Minutes of data.[image: My progress so far]

But before I invest more time into research, I must know if this goal is even possible. If not I'll have to look into other charts. Thanks for your help!

Here is the source for the above image (my_data is actually read from a csv, but filled with random junk here):

```
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime

my_data = list()
for i in range(3000):
    my_data.append((datetime.fromtimestamp(i + time.time()), np.random.randint(50, 200), np.random.randint(10, 100)))

hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
fig = plt.figure()

actg = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)  # two rows, one column, first plot
plt.ylim(50, 210)

atoco = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)  # second plot
plt.ylim(0, 100)

actg.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
actg.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

atoco.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
atoco.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
times = []
fhr1 = []
toco = []
for key in my_data:
    times.append(key[0])
    fhr1.append(key[1])
    toco.append(key[2])
actg.plot_date(times, fhr1, '-')
atoco.plot_date(times, toco, '-')

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share your code as a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: @tom: Just did that, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's something close to what you are after, I think.

I've used [`dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=[0,30])`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.SecondLocator) to set the grid every 30 seconds (also need to make sure the grid is set on the minor ticks, with `ax.xaxis.grid(True,which='both')`

To repeat the `yticklabels`, I create a [`twinx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx) of the axes for every major tick on the xaxis, and move the [spine](http://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html) to that tick's location. I then set the spine color to none, so it doesn't show up, and turn of the actual ticks, but not the tick labels.

```
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime

# how often to show xticklabels and repeat yticklabels:
xtickinterval = 10

# Make random data
my_data = list()
for i in range(3000):
    my_data.append((datetime.fromtimestamp(i + time.time()), np.random.randint(120, 160), np.random.randint(10, 100)))

hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
fig = plt.figure()

actg = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)  # two rows, one column, first plot
actg.set_ylim(50, 210)

atoco = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2,sharex=actg)  # second plot, share the xaxis with actg
atoco.set_ylim(-5, 105)

# Set the major ticks to the intervals specified above. 
actg.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=np.arange(0,60,xtickinterval)))
# Set the minor ticks to every 30 seconds
minloc = dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=[0,30])
minloc.MAXTICKS = 3000
actg.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minloc)
# Use the formatter specified above
actg.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

times = []
fhr1 = []
toco = []

for key in my_data:
    times.append(key[0])
    fhr1.append(key[1])
    toco.append(key[2])

print times[-1]-times[0]

# Make your plot
actg.plot_date(times, fhr1, '-')
atoco.plot_date(times, toco, '-')

for ax in [actg,atoco]:
    # Turn off the yticklabels on the right hand side
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

    # Set the grids
    ax.xaxis.grid(True,which='both',color='r')
    ax.yaxis.grid(True,which='major',color='r')

    # Create new yticklabels every major tick on the xaxis
    for tick in ax.get_xticks():
        tx = ax.twinx()
        tx.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
        tx.spines['right'].set_position(('data',tick))
        tx.spines['right'].set_color('None')
        for tic in tx.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
            tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks really good! So close to what I need, I'm blown away. :D Now I'll really dig into matplotlib, I'll have to color the grid (green or red, users choice) and other stuff. But this was the major obstacle I saw. Thanks tons!

Comment: Ah, sorry. Quick follow-up on this. With 300 seconds of data this works fine. But I normally would encounter more... like ten times more at least. With a bit over 3000 seconds I get following run time error: RRuleLocator estimated to generate 3049 ticks from 2016-02-23 15:21:41.581725+00:00 to 2016-02-23 16:12:31.099945+00:00: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS * 2 (2000)    --- Any thoughts or advice on that?

Comment: you can set the minor tick locator's `MAXTICKS` parameter. It's 1000 be default. I found by setting it to 1500 what seems to work for 3000 seconds. In my edited example above, I set it to 3000 to give you some wiggle room. (I also changed the grid to red for you)